# Managed hosting for Java websites?

Tags: java, jsp, web-hosting

What is a good managed hosting service for server side Java code which uses Tomcat servers? I want something that is like [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/) (for Ruby), [Gondor](http://gondor.io) (for Python), [no.de](http://no.de) (for node.js). I know there is Google App Engine out there but I am not a fan of the GAE - I want my plain-old tomcat server side code hosted in a clean, cheap, managed way like the aforementioned websites.

Comment: You meant Google App Engine, instead of GWT right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question - I found the exact thing I was looking for. The [Play framework](http://www.playframework.org/) is a clean, concise and easy to use Java web framework and they have a drop-and-forget (but slightly pricey) managed hosting available at [PlayApps](http://www.playapps.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I've had good experiences with my current host: [Java Web Hosting](http://www.cheap-jsp-hosting.com/).  Good service when things go wrong (generally because of something I did) & reliable servers.

Disclaimer:  Java Web Hosting hosts 4 sites for me, free of charge.  They put no conditions on the hosting, but I figured they deserved a link from pages of my sites.

Comment: Thanks for the info! A Google search for "managed tomcat java hosting" yields of tons of results like these but none of them seemed as polished (not just pretty landing page but modern features like git-based workflow, dependency management, easy to use console, tiered pricing) etc. These websites (atleast on the first page of Google) all seemed circa-2000ish.